# "Three or more groups" vs. "Three groups or more"

Tags: word-order

In a paper I am writing there are two sections: one deals with two groups, and the other deals with more than two groups. I am wondering which of the following titles is better for the second section:

> Three Groups or More

vs.

> Three or More Groups

?

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is more *stylistic* as both would be understood to mean the same thing.

> Three or More Groups

would probably be more common and has more of an emphasis on the group*ings* if that's what's important in your paper

> **One or Two Groups**  vs **Three or More Groups**